# How to install two different version of a specific package in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, version, apache-calcite

I'm connecting to 2 different DB, and their JDBC client both requires the package `org.apache.calcite.avatica`, one is using version 1.6, and another is using version 1.8, so I need to install both the versions (1.6 and 1.8), and seems that the version 1.8 is not compatible with version 1.6, when I'm using the version 1.8 instead of 1.6, the following exception was thrown:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.<init>(AvaticaConnection.java:117)
    org.apache.kylin.jdbc.KylinConnection.<init>(KylinConnection.java:51)
    org.apache.kylin.jdbc.KylinJdbcFactory.newConnection(KylinJdbcFactory.java:77)
    org.apache.calcite.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:143)
    org.apache.kylin.client.method.KylinJdbcMethod.getJdbcConnection(KylinJdbcMethod.java:45)
    org.apache.kylin.client.Kylin.getJdbcConnection(Kylin.java:175)
```

And it seems that Maven is not designed to use like that.

So, what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Post the output from `mvn dependency:tree`. It's still possible that you're somehow pulling in mismatched versions that can be reconciled.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. This isn't an issue with Maven, it's an issue with the standard Java classloading infrastructure.

Theoretically, you could use something like OSGi, which partitions off classloaders and permits multiple imports of classes with the same fully-qualified name, but that adds *substantial* complication.

I would make *certain* that the 1.8 library can't communicate with 1.6 (database drivers are usually backward-compatible), and if it can't, then reorganize your project to have an adaptation service. It seems that you may have misunderstood *what Calcite is*, since it itself is an adaptation layer, not a storage service, and you may simply need to update whatever queries were written in 1.6 to 1.8.

Comment: But the problem is, the calcite requirement is not required directly by myself, but by two different db's jdbc client, and I can't change the code inside the jdbc client...

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain how to make Avatica 1.6 and 1.8 work alongside each other in maven. It looks as it we broke backwards compatibility in Avatica in either [CALCITE-836](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CALCITE-836) or [CALCITE-1213](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CALCITE-1213), and on behalf of the Apache Calcite Avatica development team, I apologize.

I logged [KYLIN-1898](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KYLIN-1898) to upgrade the version of Avatica that Kylin uses.